# Hidden Theorem Style

Tags: theorems

i'm using the theorem environment to write edition notes or
commentaries in an article.

```
\declaretheorem[
    style=myexamplestyle,
    name={\ding{46} Note },
    unnumbered
]{note}
```

Is there a way to tell latex to ignore this type of theorem and print nothing in the final pdf file? I want to avoid deleting note by note. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please turn your code into a complete, minimal example we can copy-paste-compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`comment`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package to ignore an environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{comment}

\declaretheorem[
    %style=myexamplestyle,
    name={\ding{46} Note },
    unnumbered
]{note}

\excludecomment{note} % comment or uncomment this line

\begin{document}

\begin{note}
some text
\end{note}

Some text outside a note.

\end{document}
```